# Date in a short text data type field... Select query trouble

Tags: sql, database, date, ms-access

In my Access database, I have a table called `customers`. In this table I have a column called `DateEntered`. The data type for the field is *short text*.

The values in this column are not coherent - they come in several variations:

- `MM-DD-YYYY`,
- `MMDDYYYY` and
- `MM/DD/YYYY`.

There doesn't seem to be any standard set.

My goal is to select all customers from 2012. I tried

```
select *
from customers
where DateEntered <('%2013') AND >('%2012');
```

but it comes up blank when I run it.

Can anyone point out what I'm failing to do correctly & more importantly explain why exactly this query doesn't work in Access? From my understanding of SQL (not very advanced) this should work.

Comment: don't use text for date columns

Comment: You must convert all the date formats into the standard date format.

Comment: Ok so just switch the field type to "date/time" and I should be good to go? Or do I have to also change my syntax?

Comment: @dan you'll need to test to make sure that you don't suffer data loss when you change the data type of the table. Additionally, you likely will need to change your syntax when referring to the field in code\queries and reports, depending upon how you refer to the field.

Comment: I am puzzled by "The data type for the field is short text" there is no short text data type in MS Access.

Comment: @Remou It's new in Access 2013.

Comment: I see, previously just Text, but now Short Text with former Memo as Long Text.

Answer (score 2):

Another variant)

```
select * from customers where RIGHT(DateEntered, 4) = '2012'
```

Comment: For me this is the simplest and probably best approach in this case

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `LIKE` operators (they're appropriate when you have a pattern using `%` and `_`):

```
select * from customers where DateEntered  like '%2013' or DateEntered  like '%2012'
```

Comment: @dan - the above is good if you're confident that the year will always be the last four characters of your date field.

Comment: The wildcard character in MS Access is `*` not `%`, also note if the format happened to be DDMMYYYY and it was the 20th of December in any year, then this may return incorrect results, only in very rare circumstances though.

Comment: The last four will always be the year, yes. Right, the wildcard is * for select but for this you would use "like('%2012')"

Comment: Nevermind, I tried *2012 and it worked. How come % doesn't work in Access? I use it everywhere else and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the database and application code, the best way to handle this is to use an actual Date field instead of text in the table.

One way to handle this would be to add a new field to the table, write a query or two to correctly convert the text values to actual date values, and populate the new field. 
At this point, you would then need to hunt down the application code the refers to this field in any way and adjust to treat the field as a date, not text. This includes your insert and update statements, report code, etc.

Finally, as a last step, I would rename the original text field (or remove it altogether) and rename the new date field to the original field name.
Once you fix the problem, querying against the field will be a piece of cake.

Alternatively, if you can't alter the table and source code, you can use the date [conversion function CDATE()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/type-conversion-functions-HA001229018.aspx) to convert the text value to an actual date. Note that you may need to guard against non-date entries (NULL or empty string values, as well as other text values that aren't really dates in the first place). The [IsDate() function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/isdate-function-HA001228863.aspx) can be your friend here.

If you have the time and patience, fixing the data and code is the better approach to take, but sometimes this isn't always feasible.

Comment: Yeah it isn't feasible here. I need the tables to contain all text data types for an application I am using, I have no control over this. It only accepts text data types. I'm guessing the best route will be using LIKE('%YEAR') on this one.